# Phonon calculations using DFPT

Tags: vasp, phonopy, phonon-dispersion, dfpt

I'm currently working on phonon calculations using Phonopy and VASP DFPT approach with a 2x2x1 supercell. I'm seeking guidance on:
K-Points Selection: How should I determine the appropriate k-points for accurate results with Phonopy and VASP DFPT?
Band Configuration File: What's the process for creating or obtaining the band configuration file for Phonopy and VASP DFPT, and what should it include?
Any insights or resources related to Phonopy, VASP, and DFPT would be greatly appreciated.
For 2D material which supercell will be right choice? whether 2×2×1 or anyother?

Answer (score 5):

**Clarifiation:**

At first let me point out that Phonons can be calculated either using **DFPT**, or **Finite Displacement** methods. You can refer to the extensive answer by ProfM [Are there differences in accuracy and reliability between the frozen phonon method and Density Functional Perturbation Theory?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1296/1554)
and his first comment to this [answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2002/1554), in which it is explained that **Supercells** are needed in **Finite Differences** because to describe a phonon of wave vector $q$ you need a supercell commensurate with it. In **DFPT**, you can have a phonon of any wave vector in the primitive cell. Thus, according to your quesiton and as you are willing to use DFPT method, there is no need for you to use a supercell in such calculation unless you have a reason for that (studying a defect, interface or super structure,etc.)

**How To:**

In general, the following steps are needed to calculate the vibrational frequencies or phonons: At first, you should have relaxed the atomic positions and/or cell you are working with (primitive cell). Pay close attention to your choice of the KPOINTS, it is recommended to use high-enough kpoints sampling during geometrical relaxation, and use similar values for your further steps as per the answer by Phil Hasnip on a similar problem I had before [The Appearance of Imaginary Frequencies in Lattice Vibration Calculations with Increasing KPOINTS](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11991/1554). Next, ensure that cell symmetries have not been broken. Once you have that done, you can go further to perform DFPT calculation of phonon modes using VASP. Finally, post-process the results to extract modes with [Phonopy](https://phonopy.github.io/phonopy/).

**Geometrical Relaxation:**

VASP provides several ways for geometrical relaxation with the ISIF tag. If the desired symmetry of the cell you have is known, but the atomic positions and/or lattice constants are not known, you shall enforce the  symmetry of the starting structure in the POSCAR fileby setting `IBRION=2`, and  `ISYM=2`. If you just want to relax the atomic positions (lattice constants fixed), choose `ISIF=2`. For relaxation of the lattice constants, choose either `ISIF=3` (cell volume can vary) or `ISIF=4` (cell volume remains fixed). On the other hadn. if the symmetry of the initial structure is not known to be correct. In this case, use `IBRION=2`, `ISYM=0` (no symmetry) and use `ISIF=3` in this case. You will get `CONTCAR` file that will be used for the next steps as `POSCAR`.

Symmetries:

When using DFPT method, the lack of symmetry could bring problems in understanding the phonon modes specifically, the assignment of irreducible representations of the normal modes. You may face this problem if the symmetry of your structure is not known and you used `IBRION=2` with `ISYM=0` and `ISIF=3`. You can potentially fix this problem by slightly editing the `CONTCAR` file (editing x,y, z components of the lattice constants to your desired symmetry) and do another relaxation with fixed lattice constants `ISIF=2` and symmetry `ISYM=2`.

**DFPT:**

Using the previous CONTCAR file as the input POSCAR file, [VASP](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Phonons_from_density-functional-perturbation_theory) carries out DFPT calculation with `IBRION=7` or `IBRION=8`. The difference between those tow options is that `IBRION=8` applies symmetry operations to reduce the number of displacements needed, while `IBRION=7` does not. However, pay attention that if you choose `IBRION=8`, you will not be able to use NCORE/NPAR parallelization. Usually the INCAR file would look like the following (assuming that you are familiar with each of those tags):

```
NCORE    = 8
KPAR     = 4 
ENCUT    = 600
ALGO     = Normal
PREC     = Accurate
EDIFF    = 1.0e-8
IBRION   = 7
NSW      = 1
ISMEAR   = 0
SIGMA    = 0.05
LASPH    = True
LREAL    = False
ADDGRID  = True
NWRITE   = 3
LEPSILON = True
```

**Phonopy:**

Upon the DFPT calculation is done, you should get the mode symmetries from the vasprun.xml file Phonopy. Firstly, generate a FORCE_CONSTANTS file with the following command:

```
phonopy --fc vasprun.xml
```

create a file named symm.conf and place the following in there:

```
IRREPS = 0 0 0 1e-3 # This is the tolerance
SHOW_IRREPS = .TRUE.
```

After creating this file:

```
phonopy --readfc --dim="1 1 1" symm.conf"
```

This command tells Phonopy to read the FORCE_CONSTANTS file, rather than the default FORCE_SETS file generated from the finite displacements method. The second argument specifies the dimensions of a supercell in terms of the primitive cell. Here, we did not create a supercell, so the scaling is 1 in each of the lattice vectors.

You can refer to the Phonopy documentation for further steps according to your needs, I will just provide the Phonon dispersion section here: You should create the file band.conf which looks like the following (this is just an example):

```
ATOM_NAME = Mo Te
DIM = 1 1 1
BAND =    0.000   0.000   0.000     0.500   0.000   0.000    0.3333  0.3333  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000     0.000   0.000   0.500     0.500   0.000   0.500     0.3333  0.3333  0.500      0.000   0.000   0.500      0.500   0.000   0.500      0.500   0.000   0.000      0.3333  0.3333  0.000      0.3333  0.3333  0.500   
BAND_LABELS= $\Gamma$ M K $\Gamma$ A L H A L M K H
```

You can use [vaspkit](https://vaspkit.com) to get this file using the option (305), then run the following command:

```
phonopy --readfc --dim="1 1 1" -p band.conf
```

You can plot the results using your favorite plotting tools, I highly recommend using [Sumo](https://smtg-bham.github.io/sumo/sumo-phonon-bandplot.html)

Comment: Is it not  obligatory to generate a supercell for phonon calculations using Phonopy DFPT? Alternatively, can it calculate for a single monolayer? Although the website suggests creating a supercell in the method, is it also capable of analyzing a single monolayer?

Comment: @FarahShehzadi, you don't need the supercell if you are following the steps I have mentioned for DFPT approach. In the case of the monolayer, you will need to add vacuum in the stacking direction to mimic the isolated monolayer, and you can use the same method but the calculation would be longer in this case due to the vacuum layer. Depending on the symmetries in the system, the finite displacement method could be computationaly more feasible in your case. You can run phonopy -d --dim="4 4 1" and see how many displacements you will get. I suggest we continue this in chat.

Comment: @Jaafer Mehrez On average, how much time do calculations take for a primitive cell in VASP-DFPT and phonopy?

Comment: @FarahShehzadi, I don’t know, it is related to your setup, how many cores of cpu you are using, and the symmetry of your structure.

Comment: @Jaafer Mehrez suppose for space group 187 hexagonal?

Comment: @FarahShehzadi, It is highly not recommended to ask new questions in the comments section, this way you are losing the chance to get an answer for your questions. When you ask a new question, it will be visible for all other users and you would have a better chance to get an answer. Regarding your last question, I honestly don't know how to estimate the calculation time.

Comment: In vasp version 5.*, which is what I have, vibrational DFTP only works for q=(0,0,0), i.e. Gamma point. So just like for finite differences, a supercell has to be used even for DFPT ...  With a supercell, Brillouin zone folding puts non-zero q-points at the zone-center. I guess phonopy "unfolds" to the primitive cell q-points. With this in mind, I don't know if there is much of an advantage to DFPT with vasp over finite differences. Note, vasp 6.* is supposedly going to have DFPT at arbitrary q-points but I don't know if it's ready and I don't have this version. Good luck!

Comment: As a bonus comment, I often use abinit's DFPT implementation at arbitrary q-points to calculate dynamical matrices and then I use the abipy interface to extract phonopy FORCE_CONSTANTS files from the abinit results. That way, I can use standard tools that interface to phonopy. abinit is free and very powerful! I can give more guidance on how to post-process abinit with phonopy if anyone is interested. Cheers!

Comment: @JaafarMehrez I tried to calculate phonon calculations for 1x1x1  of monolayer of graphene i get wrong phonon band plot while for 4 4 1 supercell of with same incar i used for 1x1x1 i get correct phonon band plot?what will be the casues?